# Wifi Does Not Work After System Update

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, inspiron

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 x64 onto a Dell Inspiron 1525. First thing I always do when installing new OSs is being it up to speed to naturally I installed all updates before proceeding further. Now the unit has rebooted and I have no wifi. I plug in an ethernet cable and don't get anything that way either.

The Inspiron is using a Broadcom wifi adapter, which I have found is known to cause issues.

It also appears I am missing certain features in my build...unless I'm just doing something wrong.  If someone could help me get my wireless adapter working I would be good to go and very greatful

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -nn` to your question please?

Comment: Or lshw -c network | grep product

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a somewhat common problem with 12.10 x64. You had wireless while on LiveCD/USB, but after installation not anymore. Recompiling the module for your Broadcom adpater is likely to solve things.

Run this on wired connection:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Now it should it be working.
Lastly, set the module to be loaded at boot time. Run this as root:

```
echo wl >> /etc/modules
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to connect your pc for a short time to a router, afterwards, go to the software centre search for additional drivers, if not installed. Open this program and choose 'Activate'. Wait some time and then, it should work again.