# Wireless working on Ubuntu 13.04 installer but fails when installed

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.04, broadcom

I have a Lenovo Y480 with a Broadcom BCM4313 card.

The ethernet and Wireless connection works using the Ubuntu 13.04 installer, however once installed both wireless and ethernet fails.

When I checked software & updates > additional drivers it detects that my device is not working.

Is there a way that I can use the drivers from the installer? Why isn't it working when installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but with Ubuntu 12.10. Recompiling the driver worked for me.
The steps I took: https://askubuntu.com/a/282058/13539

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but I fixed it by **going to the BIOS menu and enabling WLAN**. If you go to your BIOS menu, usually by pressing F2 or Delete on start up, there should be some setting somewhere called, or similar to, Onboard Devices, and you can enable or disable it there.